# Mongodb Is there a way to guarantee no-stale data read from Secondaries

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Problem statment:

- I m trying to distribute the load to secondaries.
- Read's are dominant.

Read data from secondaries, that are not stale.

Thing's i tried.
-  read preference  as nearest
-   write concern - majority(to ensure majority of the servers are in sync)

```
@Override
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "mars.mongodb.readWrite.concern.majority", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(this.mongoDbFactory(), this.mappingMongoConverter());
        template.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.nearest());
        template.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY);
        return template;
    }
```

Some read's:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#sessions

Comment: Could you elaborate why casual consistency guarantees don't suffice in your case? The page you refer in the question reads: *you issue a write with "majority" write concern followed by a read that reads from a secondary (i.e. read preference secondary) with "majority" read concern, the read operation will reflect the state of the database after the write operation.* which seems to answer your question directly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexBlex  Yes, but i had concern that what if the data i m reading is not written to the secondary(but written to other majority secondaries) which i am reading(with read concern majority) from, then it won't get that data, it's as good as i am not getting data because of stale state.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure if it is possible to re-word the phrase "the read operation will reflect the state of the database after the write operation"  in a simpler way but it actually guarantees the consistency you are asking for. It is one of the main reasons for client sessions to exist. Are you concerns based on any particular problem or just a fear of unknown? I am just trying to understand what kind of guarantees you expect if the statement from the docs isn't good enough for you? If you can prove it wrong, it's a bug and should be reported immediately since many good people rely on it.

Comment: yes new to mongodb, pardon me for being ambiguous.

You are suggesting that in a client session we have casual consistency ?
What if i did this at application level. does all the mongo operation are performed in a session ?(then only can it provide casual consistency at application level right ?)

Comment: Please read the pages you mentioned in "Some read's" and may be https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.sessions applied to spring. 
Client sessions are the instrument to achieve causal consistency. You need to write your application using sessions and ensure you don't query mongo with the same session in different threads - it will breach T&Cs and void the warranty. Also please read the small print. The consistency is guaranteed only within the session. It seems to fit into your case if I get it, but please learn how it works. It's an advanced topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexBlex for your insight this is really very helpful will go through the link's and look for some advance topic's for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

With some of insight from @alex-blex and @Markus W Mahlberg compiled my finding's in blog, with some ways to read from secondaries.

https://medium.com/@arun2pratap/mongodb-read-from-secondary-to-boost-performance-dca938a680ac

Answer (score 1):

Replica sets are not the means to distribute load in a MongoDB cluster. That is what sharded clusters are there for, with each shard being responsible for a subset of the data.

The only way to ensure that a document is in sync on all members of a replica set is to use the write concern that equals the number of members in your replica set, since the write is only acknowledged when all members received it and applied it to at least the journal. However, setting the write concern to the number of your members, you loose the failover capabilities of a replica set. If one member of your replica set fails, the write concern cannot be matched any more and no further writes will be accepted.

Comment: Is there a way to only read from secondaries that are not lagging by giving maxStalness ? but the documentation says not to value less than 60 second's.

Thanks a lot for such a prompt answer :)

Comment: my use case the concern is only when i m performing write and reading it back in the next call from the same thread that should not be stale, 
It should not read stale right ? as it should read from the cache ?

Comment: @ArunPratapSingh "It should", "it could"... And the answer is "probably". The only way to make *sure* is to apply a tool as it is intended to be. A replica set is not there for load balancing and can only be used in such capacity when your application (and/or users) can live with eventual consistency or the loss of failover capabilities, as described above. The setup you need to ensure getting consistent reads with load balancing is to use a sharded cluster.

Answer (score 1):

By design, a secondary may lag behind the primary. In general a read from a secondary is appropriate when the latest data is *not* required.

To make your secondaries contain up-to-date data, you can write with the write concern equal to the number of data bearing nodes in the replica set. This will impact availability (any node going down will stall writes).

Max staleness is a *rough* estimate of staleness and can be used to specify how much replication lag, in general, an application can accept when querying secondaries. It is not a way to obtain a majority read.